# Using TinyIoC with MonoTouch + Storyboard - Where to build up?

Tags: c#, ios, dependency-injection, xamarin.ios, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to use dependency injection in MonoTouch using TinyIoC, however I can't seem to figure out where I should do the registration, and the buildup that injects my services in my controller (is that the correct terminology?)

I created a new MonoTouch Storyboard Project, looked thru the files, and I can't find the code that instantiates my controller.

I have tried to create a constructor on my `AppDelegate`, and do the type registration there, and then the `container.BuildUp(this);` in my controller's constructor. However I have a feeling that this is wrong.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems right to me.

I would move the registrations to the `DidFinishLaunching` in your `AppDelegate`, though.

The problem with storyboards are that all your controllers get created from Objective-C, which is why the `IntPtr` constructor is used.  Really the constructor of your controller is the only good place to call `BuildUp`.

Are you have any problems with the way it is working now?

Another option is to use a different type of container, I seem to prefer a simpler one (than even TinyIoC).  [Here](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils/blob/master/XPlatUtils/ServiceContainer.cs) is one I wrote.

Comment: Small world, I've read your thread on the Xamarin forums :) - The first thing I tried was doing the registration in the DidFinishLaunching, however that didn't work due to the fact that the controller is instantiated before that method is called, so it basically did the BuildUp before anything was registered.

Comment: - yes, it works perfectly fine this way, was just looking for some "best practices". I modified the TinyIoC with a Dependency attribute, so only the properties of my choosing get processed by it.

Comment: Yeah, using the constructor in an `AppDelegate` is probably where you'll have to put it then.  Another option is in the `static void Main()`, but I don't know if that is any better or worse.  Overall I'd say your approach is fine.